# Outlook addin not loading on second instance

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have successfully created an addin for Outlook which shows/hides a custom task pane using a ribbon toggle button by following this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608590.aspx#Anchor_4).

The problem I have is it works fine for one instance of Outlook, but as soon as I open another instance pressing the ribbon button only controls the addin on the first instance.

The ribbon code:

```
    public partial class ManageTaskPaneRibbon
    {
    private void ManageTaskPaneRibbonLoad(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        btnToggle.Tag = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    private void BtnToggleClick(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.TaskPane.Visible = ((RibbonToggleButton)sender).Checked;
    }
    }
```

I need the 2 instances to be completely separate in operation so they can work independently from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Application.Explorers.NewExplorer event fires, create a new task pane for that instance of the Explorer object.

Comment: I have read something about doing this elsewhere, but the problem I have is the ribbon only contains 1 button to toggle the pane on and off so how do I control the visibility of the panes and checked state of the button?

Comment: You need to keep a list of task panes - one for each explorer. When the callbacks for your .ribbon buttons fire, you will have the Explorer as the parameter, the values your return and actions you take must be Explorer object instance specific, not global.